# Comma separated values within JSP for-each tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to get a JSTL `<c:forEach>` tag to work so that it would print a list of names as follows:

```
Best, Milo, Kane
```

My code is as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
    ${person.name}, 
</c:forEach>
```

However, on the last person/name, a comma is inserted at the end, e.g.

```
Best, Milo, Kane,
```

How can I avoid the last comma in the loop?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use [`LoopTagStatus#isLast`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast%28%29)

```
<c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person" varStatus="loop">
    ${person.name}
   <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

A simpler solution is to use a [conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) within `EL` instead of the `if` tag

```
${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus, that helped a lot :)

Comment: The code is even slimmer if you invert the conditional:  `${loop.last ? '' : ','}`